# how to add an array in stdClassObject php

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have an array like this:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => ABC [sentece] => blablabla... [topic] => Science ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [title] => DEF [sentece] => nomnomnom... [topic] => Technology )

How to add an array in stdClass Object in php?

For example: I want to add this array:

```
$number = array (82, 61);
```

So, I will have this array:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [title] => ABC [sentece] => blablabla... [topic] => Science *[number] => 82*) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [title] => DEF [sentece] => nomnomnom... [topic] => Technology 
>   [number] => 61

)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are you stuck on this task in particular? Are you looking for the property accessor `->`?

Comment: I think he wants to distibute the array elements over the existing array so each array object contains a number from $number array

Comment: yes, that's my point Mr. Muhannad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information you provided, you'll need to do that manually.

**Manual Entry**

```
$Array = [
    //your array
];
$Array[0]->number = 82;
$Array[1]->number = 61;
```

**Automated?**

```
$Array = [
    //your array
];
$Numbers = [82, 61];
foreach($Numbers as $key => $number) {
    if(isset($Array[$key]) {
        $Array[$key]->number = $number;
    }
}
```